# WordPress 4.4 <picture> responsive sometimes doesn't work

Tags: post-thumbnails, responsive

When WordPress 4.4 was released, it added the ability to make your feature images responsive using the picturefill JavaScript libraries. Is anyone else having problems with the `<picture>` tag? Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Code I'm using for responsive feature images:

```
<picture>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-499px" media="(max-width: 599px)"></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-120x90.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)"></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-220x116.jpg"></a>
<!-- fallback -->
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-220x116.jpg" alt="alt text"></a>
</picture>
```

When I copy an example code css-tricks.com, this works:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-499px" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
<source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-120x90.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
<source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg.jpg"> 
<!-- fallback -->
<img srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg.jpg" alt="alt text">
</picture>
```

Then I replace the media elements with the ones from the first example. Any ideas what's causing this to work then not work when I add another post or change the feature image?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by removing the `<a href>` from the image. This is the proper way of doing a responsive image with a link:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<picture>
<source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-499px" media="(max-width: 599px)">
<source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-120x90.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
<source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-220x116.jpg">
<!-- fallback -->
<img srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/noimg-220x116.jpg" alt="alt text">
</picture>
</a>
```